# Bubble sort with Number field in Wrapper Class List

Tags: apex, visualforce, datatable, sort, tablesorter

I would need some idea on how to sort a number column in Wrapper class.

Wrapper class list is received from Callout and not by querying any SoBject.
So cannot use ASC/DESC.

Tried out comparable Interface - It works only for String.

Any example on how to refer elements during the bubble sort would help:

```
Wrapper class Field - SerialNumber (get ;set}

   for (integer i = 0 ; i <List.size() ; i++ ) {
       for ( j = 0 ; j<List.size() ; j++) {
          //HOW TO REFER TO THE FIELD WHILE COMPARISON
       }
   }
```

Comment: Comparable can work equally well for any data type. Please share the specific code you have tried. Your current code isn't even valid syntax.

Comment: The [comparable interface example code in the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm) is pretty solid. Did you check it out? Did it not work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Adrian Larson and Mark Pond mentioned, Comparable can work equally well for any data type.

Here is an example on how to implement it. If the member variable type is not String (in your case Integer), you have to write the comparison logic instead of the default String `CompareTo` method. Let's take the below example, there is Student Class having Name (String) and Age (Integer) variable. Now check the difference between two versions, where first one is using Name for comparison and Second one is for Age Comparison. Hope this helps.

***Comparison based on Name***

```
global class Student implements Comparable {
    global String StudentName {get;set;}    
    global Integer StudentAge {get; set;}

    global Student(String Name, Integer Age) {
        StudentName = Name;
        StudentAge = Age;
    }
    global Integer compareTo(Object ObjToCompare) {
        return StudentName.CompareTo(((Student)ObjToCompare).StudentName);
    }        
}
```

***Comparison based on Age***

```
global class Student implements Comparable {
    global String StudentName {get;set;}    
    global Integer StudentAge {get; set;}

    global Student(String Name, Integer Age) {
        StudentName = Name;
        StudentAge = Age;
    }
    global Integer compareTo(Object ObjToCompare) {
        Student compareToStud = (Student)ObjToCompare;
        if (StudentAge == compareToStud.StudentAge) return 0;
        if (StudentAge > compareToStud.StudentAge) return 1;
        return -1;
    }        
}
```

You can find more details in the below links.

1 - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm

2 - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_list_sorting_sobject.htm

Comment: Your answer would be much more relevant if you sorted based on age instead.

Comment: Yes it is there, the second code snippet compares the age.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. It's kind of buried but is indeed included.